how to fix error that integrate next.js and thirdweb?
I have one error that integrate next.js and thirdweb.
That is, if I don't add ThirdwebProvider, project compile succeed, but if I add ThirdwebProvider, project compile fail.
Who can help me?
This is my code snippet
Here, if I execute with "yarn dev" command, compile fail.
This is executing result
layout.tsx
// layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Space_Mono, Work_Sans } from "next/font/google";
import localFont from "next/font/local";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import "./globals.css";
import "../css/line-area-chart.css";
import "../css/scatter-time-chart.css";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import IntercomChat from "../components/ui/IntercomChat/IntercomChat.jsx";
import { IntercomProvider } from "../context/IntercomContext";
import { ThirdwebProvider } from "thirdweb/react";

const spacemono = Space_Mono({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["400", "700"],
  variable: "--space-mono-font",
});
const worksans = Work_Sans({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["400", "700"],
  variable: "--work-sans-font",
});

const suisseintl = localFont({
  src: "../public/font/SuisseIntl-Regular.ttf",
  variable: "--suisseintl-font",
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Prismatic Capital",
  description:
    "Prismatic Capital is a cryptoasset investment firm. We invest in the entire spectrum of digital assets, with an emphasis on decentralized finance.",
};

export const revalidate = 3600; // revalidate at most every hour

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
      <body
        className={`${suisseintl.variable} ${spacemono.variable} ${worksans.variable} font-body`}
      >
        <div className="relative overflow-hidden">
          <ThirdwebProvider>
            <IntercomProvider>
              {children}
              <Toaster />
              <IntercomChat />
              <Footer />
            </IntercomProvider>
          </ThirdwebProvider>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


What's the error message?
